# How did 真っ赤 came to mean "downright"?

Tags: etymology, colors

We know that 真っ赤 means "deep red," but how did it come to mean 'downright', as in 真っ赤な嘘 (outright lie)?

Comment: http://gogen-allguide.com/ma/makkanauso.html

Answer (score 1):

真っ赤 doesn't mean deep red, it's an emphatic expression of being red.

It comes form suffix ma and reduplicated adjectives.

1. ma aka aka --> makkakka --> makka (まっかっか is still a word)
2. ma kuro kuro --> makkuro

Edit: Sorry, my answer was irrelevant to OP's question.

Comment: This reduplication theory is really interesting!  Is there somewhere I can read more?  I'm curious how /massao/ fits in.